# Using OR and AND in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query as follow: (shows are a table with tv shows and IMDB ID and recommended_titles is a table with two columns with IMDB_ID)

```
Select t2.* from shows t, shows t2, recommended_titles WHERE 
t.imdb_id = recommended_titles. title_id_1 
AND recommended_titles.title_id_2=t2.imdb_id 
AND t.imdb_id = 0367279 LIMIT 7
```

The query is fine but I realized that it was only checking in the first column for my imdb id when it can also appear in my second one.
So i try to add the following:

```
OR
recommended_titles.title_id_2=t.imdb_id 
AND t.imdb_id = recommended_titles. title_id_1 
AND t.imdb_id = 0367279 LIMIT 7
```

But apparently OR can't be used with AND,

any suggestions as how I should do this ?

Edit:
To explain what I'm trying to do, here's a quick example in case my explanations above are too confusing.
table shows has rows like this:

```
name of a tv show | 00001
name of another   | 00002
name of another   | 00003
```

table recommended titles has (notice that an ID can be in either column)

```
00001 |  00002
00002 |  00003
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may look at [operator precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) in mysql (and see that `AND` has an higher precedence than `OR`), or use parenthesis (much easier to use and maintain)

```
(t.imdb_id = recommended_titles.title_id_1 OR
recommended_titles.title_id_2=t.imdb_id)

AND recommended_titles.title_id_2=t2.imdb_id 
AND t.imdb_id = 0367279 LIMIT 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this,

```
(recommended_titles.title_id_2=t.imdb_id 
      OR t.imdb_id = recommended_titles. title_id_1)
AND t.imdb_id = 0367279 LIMIT 7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(t.imdb_id = recommended_titles. title_id_1 
OR recommended_titles.title_id_2=t.imdb_id )
AND t.imdb_id = 0367279 LIMIT 7
```

Just use parenthesis to group your conditions for priorities.